# Highcharts Series Margins

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Looking since a while to this issue, but I can't find a correct answer.

See attached picture. How can I control/increase the margins of the chart drawing ONLY? Axis and the rest should stay as they are, I would like to make the margin between the Y Axis and the Chart Itself bigger.

Is this somehow possible?

Fiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/klodoma/ood4vykf/1/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Average Monthly Weather Data for Tokyo'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        crosshair: true
    }],
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}°C',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            }
        },
        opposite: true

    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} mm',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        }

    }],
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        x: 80,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 55,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Rainfall',
        //type: 'spline',
        yAxis: 0,
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 18.5, 26.4, 14.1, 195.6, 154.4],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' mm'
        }

    }, 
             {
        name: 'Rainfall2',
        type: 'spline',
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [19.9, 73.5, 100.4, 111.2, 134.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' mm'
        }

    }]
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:
The [offset](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.offset) property of the xAxis and yAxis from the Highcharts API can be used.

The "***trick***" is to specify the [offset](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.offset) just to the ***first*** axis and not to all of them.

```
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}°C',
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature',
        },
        offset: 150
    },{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}°C',
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature',
        },
        //offset: 50 //do not set this value
    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall',
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} mm',
        },
        opposite: true,
        offset: 50 //set this value, it's an opposite axis!
    }],
```

A full example is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/klodoma/2k4akses/3/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the [offset](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.offset) of the `yAxis` object using the Highcharts API.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mariocatch/d1e6h96y/1/

```
yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
    labels: {
        format: '{value}°C',
        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
        },
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Temperature',
        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
        }
    },
    opposite: true,            
    offset: 50
}, { // Secondary yAxis
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Rainfall',
        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        }
    },
    labels: {
        format: '{value} mm',
        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        }
    },
    offset: 50
}]
```

Comment: Yes, this is just a partial solution. Once I have multiple axis on one side, the offset doesn't help anymore, the position is absolute. See this one:
http://jsfiddle.net/klodoma/ctj24zqr/1/

It would help me a setting to manage the "inner chart" margins or padding or something like that.

Comment: Yes, the offset did the trick it's just a special case how to use it! I will provide a full answer. 

Thank you!

Comment: @Klodoma You could increase offset of second axis - http://jsfiddle.net/ctj24zqr/2/ When you will decrease a size of a plot area axes should follow and be down sized too - otherwise you would end up with labels on axis that doesn't show anything - like categories on xAxis - what should be displayed? You could control [margins](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.margin) to change plot area distance from edges of a chart - http://jsfiddle.net/d1e6h96y/2/